# How to pass a multidimentional array in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to pass `inv` array in ajax? I got the `inv` array value in console.log but I cannot get the array in my php page.

```
<script>
var FilterCat=['Location','Name','City','Country','State'];
var inv =[];

for(var j = 0; j < FilterCat.length; j++) 
{
    var a =  FilterCat[j];
    a =[];
    var apply = document.getElementsByName("Filter['"+FilterCat[j]+"'][]");

    for(var i = 0; i < apply.length; i++) {
        if(apply[i].checked)
        {
            var F =  a.push(apply[i].value);
        }
    }
    inv[FilterCat[j]]=a;
}

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : "../module/ApplyFilter.php",
    data :{data:inv},
    dataType :'JSON',
    success:function(response)
    {
        alert(response);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
<script>
```

After for loop I will get a value in each array variable but in ajax data will return black array

Here category wise value set in its particular array and i need to pass in one main array in ajax.

My Console response is like this:

```
City: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
Country: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
State: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
Location: Array(2)
0: "Distributore"
1: "Vendor"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
Name: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Send as JSON with JSON.stringyfy(data)

Comment: i did but in response i will get blank array i.e. array()

Answer (score 0):

Your query selector is not correct. You need to specify the `name` attribute, and put quotes around the whole value, not just the part inside the subscript. And an attribute selector has to be inside square brackets. So it should be:

```
var apply = document.querySelectorAll("[name='Filter["+FilterCat[j]+"][]']");
```

Other than that, your code should work. In PHP, the values you want will be in `$_POST['data']['Location']`, `$_POST['data']['Name']`, etc.

The extra `data` wrapper is not really needed, though. If you do:

```
data: inv
```

Then in PHP you'll be able to get the values from `$_POST['Location']`, `$_POST['Name']`, etc.

In either case, these will be arrays of the checkbox values.

You can also simplify the JavaScript code by adding `:checked` to your selector, so you don't need to check that in the loop.

```
var apply = document.querySelectorAll("[name='Filter["+FilterCat[j]+"][]']:checked");
var a = apply.map(el => el.value);
inv[FilterCat[j]]=a;
```

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'name='Filter[LocationCenterType][]':checked' is not a valid selector.
    at ApplyFilter

Comment: I forgot the square brackets around the attribute selector.

Comment: Ok But Still Give erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at ApplyFilter

Comment: You need to use `QuerySelectorAll` to get all the matches so you can loop over them.

Comment: extreamly sorry for taking your valuable time